# ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value).map is not a function

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular5, angularfire2

I`m learning ANGULAR 5 CRUD application using google. firebase service and following video tutorial [from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEdxydnpNFs&t=330s), and I got this [error](https://monosnap.com/file/9rv84ZVh3l7h8H24lkBdgnQ1ZBcZhA)

```
ngOnInit() {
  var x = this.employeeService.getData();
  x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
    this.employeeList = [];
    item.forEach(element => {
      var y = element.payload.toJSON();
      y["$key"] = element.key;
      this.employeeList.push(y as Employee);
    });
  });
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: please show your `employeeService`.

Comment: http://take.ms/OtYbk

Comment: sorry, but the above link is not working for me. Please use SO itself for posting question-related stuff.

Comment: where are u using map() function in ur code??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 this.employeeList.push(y);
```

Comment: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Employee'

Comment: yes. details are not enough.i want all ts files for give a good solution.sorry for the late.